# Troubleshooting insert/delete/select performance on Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a web app with Python API that is reading/write to an Oracle database. The API is designed in such a way :-

- it uses only one connection object to Oracle (SQLAlchemy)
- when user makes some data change on the app, we delete the records from two tables and insert new records (delete, insert, delete, insert happens sequentially)
- two users will not be able to concurrently delete or insert the same keys, but they may concurrently delete or insert from the same table but with different keys
- at the same time other users may be loading other screens where we run select from the same tables
- currently we have only 3-5 users testing the app concurrently but eventually we don't expect total concurrent usage to cross 30-40 users

so the issue here is that the DB performance is quite inconsistent e.g. to delete one record from table A may take 1 second, and sometimes to delete one record from table A may take 8 seconds. from my investigation it seems like Oracle does not employ any table level locks, only row level locks so the read and write should not conflict with each other - hence it should not be a concurrency issue. I'm also not sure if using multiple connections or connection pooling will improve the performance. So in summary I'm looking for ways I can troubleshoot this to find out why there is such a difference in performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have time and some DBA skills, try to install and configure Statspack (no additional licensing needed), take snaphosts and issue a Statspack report to have a detailed instance activity report. Statspack is documented in $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/spdoc.txt.

If not try to use lab128 free version for a couple of days: it has some really nice features to analyze database live activity including a kind of Statspack live: you don't need to install anything on database side.

You can also try to use SQL Developer (free Oracle tool): it has some limited features for performance analysis (The Instance Viewer) but be careful: advanced features usage may trigger usage of additional licensed options.

(I assume that you don't have the license to use AWR but if you have it, just use AWR report).

If Oracle runs on Linux you can try to install MOATS which a light tool to have  a 'top' like tool for database sessions:
https://github.com/oracle-developer/moats